# asp login - open a new window if authentication is successful

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, forms-authentication

I need to open a new window if the authentication of a users login is successful. is there an easy way to have the DestinationPageUrl open in a new window using something like target="_blank" ? below is my code:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <br />
        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Public/Index.aspx" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">
                </asp:Login>
            </AnonymousTemplate>
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                Welcome User
            </LoggedInTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
        <br />        
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you expect to have happen with the current (login) window?

Comment: Why do you want to open a new window? Generally that's a bad idea and makes the user-experience suffer (as users expect websites to be self-contained within a window browser tab unless they explicitly open a link in a new tab or window).

Comment: The login is used inter-office so I dont need to worry about user expectations. The reason behind using a popup window is becuase the destination pages are gridview database entry pages. I want those pages to have little format as possible and not be incompassed in our company intranet site.

Comment: I have been trying to get the response.redirect to work but with no luck. can anyone help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I would code the page with two  controls, one for login. Once the login is successful, hide the login and display your form. No redirect necessary.